# How to make input pop out and show whole content

Tags: html, css

I have multiple inputs and for some of them the input is to small to display the whole text (can not be changed). Is there a way to show the whole content of the input when hovering without breaking the rest of the layout? I included an example. I am trying to have the input pop out and be on top of the other inputs without breaking the design.

https://jsfiddle.net/14e37gj0/

I am not realy good with css.
I tried something like this.

```
input {
  width: 10%;
}

input:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

First way to come on my mind was using `Flexbox`

so first of all, you need to wrap all your `input` tags with a wrapper like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="This text is long and I want to see the whole input when hovering" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

And in CSS add the following rules

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

input:hover {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

The `flex: 1 1 auto` is the one responsible to fill remaining gap until the end of the row.

Things could still be more efficient, but i tried to make it as simple as possible, and i suggest you learn more about CSS `Flexbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `input`s in a flexbox div:

```css
.row{
  display:flex;
  width:100%;
}
input {
  width: 10%;
}

input:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<input type="text" value="This text is long and I want to see the whole input when hovering"/>

<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***javascript*** to create a **mouseover** and **mouseout** ***event*** to create an ***absolutely*** positioned element, then pass the value of the `event.target` into its content. Use `insertAdjacentHTML` to add it on `mouseover` and use `.remove()` to remove it on `mouseout`. Check the inputs `clientWidth` with the inputs `scrollWidth` to see if you have ***overflow***, if you do, insertAdjacentHTML span tag with class of `.content` with the `e.target.value` as its content.

**See below code in snip it with full explanation of code above each line:**

```js
// get nodelist of all inputs
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

// function for the event listeners, pass the event into it as poarameter => e
function showAllContent(e) {
  // the following positions will be used to position our 
  // absolutely positioned span tag below the event.target element
  // get the top position of the event target => "input" being hovered
  let top = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top
  // get the left position of the event target => "input" being hovered
  let left = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left  
  // get the height of the event target => "input" being hovered
  let height = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().height
  
  /* set a root variable for e.target top and left to be used in CSS to style
     the position of the absolutely positioned span tag
     NOTE: if you change the inputs layout of have elements below, 
     you will likely have to play with these settings a bit */
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--e-target-top', `${top + height}px`)
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--e-target-left', `${left}px`)
  // set variable for event target value
  let allContent = e.target.value.trim()
  // set variable to show all of event.target.value
  let span = `<span class="content">${allContent}</span>`
  // conditional to make sure event.target is not null and also
  // make sure its scrollWidth is greater than its clientWidth
  if (allContent && e.target.scrollWidth > e.target.clientWidth) {
    // check type of event is mouseover
    if (e.type === 'mouseover') {
      // insert the span tag into the DOM
      e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', span)         
    }
    // check type of event is mouseout and .content is set
    if (e.type === 'mouseout' && document.querySelector('.content')) {
      // remove the element from DOM
      document.querySelector('.content').remove()
    }
  }
}

// iterate over the input nodeList
inputs.forEach(input => {
  // event listener for mouseover
  input.addEventListener('mouseover', showAllContent)
  // event listener for mouseout
  input.addEventListener('mouseout', showAllContent)
})
```

```css
:root {
  /* this will set our top position in the .content class it is being sent  
     from JS using style.setProperty('--e-target-top', `${top + height}px`) */
  --e-target-top: 0;
  /* this will set our left position in the .content class it is being sent  
     from JS using style.setProperty('--e-target-left', `${left}px`) */
  --e-target-left: 0;
}

input {
  width: 10%;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--e-target-left);
  top: var(--e-target-top);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <input type="text" value="This text is long and I want to see the whole input when hovering" />
  <input type="text" value="small text" />
  <input type="text" value="this inputs scrollWidth will overflow the clientWidth" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```